# How to capture live transformations of a rigid body?

Tags: python, scripting, keyframes, csv

I've tried several scripts and all of them capture the initial object's data and record the same values for all frames. What would I be doing wrong?

```
import bpy
import random

# set up the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

# add a cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, location=(0, 0, 5))
bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()
cube = bpy.context.active_object
cube.name = "Cube"
cube.color = (0, 0, 1, 0)  # blue
cube.rigid_body.type = 'ACTIVE'

# randomize the cube's rotation and scale
cube.rotation_euler = (random.uniform(0, 360), random.uniform(0, 360), random.uniform(0, 360))
cube.scale = (random.uniform(0.5, 2), random.uniform(0.5, 2), random.uniform(0.5, 2))

# add a ground plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=10, location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()
ground = bpy.context.active_object
ground.name = "Ground"
ground.color = (0, 1, 0, 0)  # green
ground.rigid_body.type = 'PASSIVE'

# set up the output file
with open("cube_properties.csv", "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write("frame,position_x,position_y,position_z,rotation_x,rotation_y,rotation_z,scale_x,scale_y,scale_z\n")
    
    # run the simulation
    for frame in range(0, 24 * 50):
        # set the current frame
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)

        # record the properties of the cube
        position = cube.location
        rotation = cube.rotation_euler
        scale = cube.scale
        output_file.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(frame, position.x, position.y, position.z, rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z, scale.x, scale.y, scale.z))
```

EDIT: I have fixed the question as per Leander's comment.

Comment: `rotation_euler` is changed, but `location` is saved to csv. `location` is not changed by the script. What values do you expect? Is this a real question?

Comment: This is [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), please tell us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Leander Hi Leander, sorry for that, hope you understand I've dealing with this for hours and now my head is the one rotating. I have updated the script, hopefully this one has some bug that I can't just identify.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Hi Markus, what I am trying to accomplish is to understand how to save physics data per frame into a tabular csv.

Comment: What physics? If rigid body physics, then read `matrix_world` rather than location.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you.

Comment: @Markus or Mauricio, could you add that as an answer, please?

Comment: @MauricioMaroto or Marcus .. I second Leander's request, to avoid closure.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working script. Thanks for the help.

```
import bpy
import csv
from random import randint


print('Simulation Started...')


def add_cube(location, rotation):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, location=location, rotation=rotation)
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add(type='ACTIVE')
    cube = bpy.context.active_object
    cube.name = 'Cube'
    return cube

def add_plane(location):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=20, enter_editmode=False, location=location)
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add(type='PASSIVE')
    plane = bpy.context.active_object
    plane.name = 'Plane'
    return plane

def write_csv(file_path, rows):
    with open(file_path, mode='w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Frame', 'Pos.X', 'Pos.Y', 'Pos.Z', 'Rot.X', 'Rot.Y', 'Rot.Z'])
        writer.writerows(rows)

# Set up the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

# Add a cube and a plane to the scene
add_cube((randint(-5, 5), randint(-5, 5), 10), (randint(-5, 5), randint(-5, 5), randint(-5, 5)))
add_plane((0, 0, 0))

# Write the location and rotation of the cube to a CSV file for each frame of the simulation
rows = []
for i in range(1, 251):
    # Set the current frame
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)

    # Get the cube object and its location and rotation
    cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
    loc = cube.matrix_world.translation
    rot = cube.matrix_world.to_euler()

    # Add the row to the list of rows
    rows.append([i, loc.x, loc.y, loc.z, rot.x, rot.y, rot.z,])

# Write the rows to the CSV file
write_csv('cube_location.csv', rows)

print('Simulation completed!')
```